# Restlet maven dependency issue error code 307

Tags: maven, maven-2, restlet

I have the following Restlet dependency that is probably coming into effect because its  transitive in nature.

However I get the following error message which stops me from building the project. Can you please let me know the issue?

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1: Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.1.1 from/to maven-restlet (http://maven.restlet.org): Failed to transfer http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom. Error code 307, Temporary Redirect -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I made a try with the version of Restlet you use (2.1.1) and same edition (jee) with the following file `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.restlet.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.maven.test</artifactId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-snapshot</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I works for me. See the following traces below:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building org.restlet.maven.test 1.0.0-snapshot
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom (614 B at 1.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.parent/2.1.1/org.restlet.parent-2.1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet.parent/2.1.1/org.restlet.parent-2.1.1.pom (9 KB at 28.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.jar
Downloaded: http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jse/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.jar (710 KB at 392.9 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ org.restlet.maven.test ---
(...)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.353s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 25 10:48:47 CET 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think that it's a problem in your maven configuration.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks,I still have the same issue  I don't have a restlet entry in my POM , however the restlet it seems is being picked up from another dependency , is it possible that that dependent entry is pointing to a different restlet repository , that is redirecting using a 307 Http error code and my eclipse client is not able to handle that ?

Comment: Do you have configured the restlet repository in your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: No, because my pom.xml is not referring to the restlet dependency directly , let me include the repository now and re-run the Maven build and let you know if this overrides the Maven repository from the dependencies somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to go beyond the compilation error?. I'm getting this error while including Morphline dependency for building a Morphline ETL job. After investigating I was not able to get an answer. I manually downloaded the pom, jar into the .m2 directory on my location and fix this issue. 
[image: Manually added files from http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.parent/2.1.1/]

I downloaded the files from  http://maven.restlet.com/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.parent/2.1.1/.

built the pom and it was successful. let me know if there was a fix to this issue which is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whatever is calling the restlet dependency in the original question is referencing http://maven.restlet.org which doesn't seem to be a good URL anymore (and it looks like it was in transition when the question was asked). It should work if you replace that with http://maven.restlet.com, which bears out in Thierry's answer.

Incidentally, I came across this same issue while trying to install DSpace 6.3, which has a dependency of Solr 4.10.4, and I want to share my solution in case others are encountering this and, like me, finding only very old and irrelevant threads about it.

My error message was almost identical except for the message returned by the server:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dspace-solr: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project org.dspace:dspace-solr:war:6.3: Failed to collect 
dependencies at org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:4.10.4 -> 
org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.1.1: Could not transfer artifact 
org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:pom:2.1.1 from/to maven-restlet 
(http://maven.restlet.org): Access denied to: 
http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.1.1/org.restlet-2.1.1.pom , 
ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
```

I resolved this by searching for .pom files in my ~/.m2 directory that contained "restlet.org" and then editing them to replace restlet.org with restlet.com, which for the version of Solr that DSpace needs was in:

```
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/solr/solr-parent/4.10.4/solr-parent-4.10.4.pom
```

And I changed from

```
    <repository>
      <id>maven-restlet</id>
      <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
```

To

```
    <repository>
      <id>maven-restlet</id>
      <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
    </repository>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the below issue with restlet jse download from maven,

> Could not resolve dependencies for project restletapi:restlet-sample-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:jar:2.3.7: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:jar:2.3.7: Could not transfer artifact org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:pom:2.3.7 from/to maven-restlet (https://maven.restlet.com): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]

You need to add the below Restlet respository in pom.xml

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>maven-restlet</id>
       <name>Restlet repository</name>
       <url>https://maven.restlet.talend.com</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```